# general form of a xindy log file

Tags: xindy

I write a maven plugin for latex. 
FOr glossaries I also want to support xindy besides the old fashioned makeindex. 
The problem is, that I have to know from the log file, 
how to detect warnings and errors.

This is quite simple for makeindex but I do not find any documentation 
on log files of xindy.

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 3):

As a last resort, you can look at xindy's source code available on [GitHub](https://github.com/jschrod/xindy.ctan). In file [`base.lsp`](https://github.com/jschrod/xindy.ctan/blob/master/src/base.lsp#L39-L46) we find format definitions

```
(defparameter *nraw-error-message* "~&WARNING: ")
(defparameter *oops-error-message* "~&ERROR: ")
```

which, as far as I understand, means that warnings start with `WARNING:` and errors with `ERROR:` at the start of a new line (followed by the actual error message).

Comment: Wow, I think this is exactly what I want. For the details I direct the user to the log files (if present; if not, this counts as a severe error).